# onload requires function to be recognized at parsing time?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this Iframe :

```
 <iframe src='http://jsbin.com/iyaVOSe/1' onload='aaa()' id='ifr'/>
```

But the onload works only if function is declared before the iframe :

**working :** (http://jsbin.com/ObeQERE/3/edit)

```
<script>  
    window.aaa= function ()
    {
      alert('load');
       
    }
 </script>
 <iframe src='http://jsbin.com/iyaVOSe/1' onload='aaa()' id='ifr'/>
```

**not working :**  (`aaa` is undefined) (http://jsbin.com/ObeQERE/4/edit)

```
 <iframe src='http://jsbin.com/iyaVOSe/1' onload='aaa()' id='ifr'/>
<script>  
    window.aaa= function ()
    {
      alert('load');
       
    }
 </script>
```

this is pretty weird becuase the onload has a bit of delay to happend , and also  - it doesnt matter when not using iframes but onclick event :

**Input working example**

```
 <input onclick='aaa()' />
      <script>  
        window.aaa= function ()
        {
          alert('load');
           
        }
       
        </script>
```

Also -in the iframe sample - : the `aaa` is translated to :

[image]

Even so -  it doesn't really need to know `aaa` at parsing time. - because there is a wrapping function.

Notice : the load event for iframe is for the page to load and not element creation.

So - when it parses the `iframe` - it starts to load the iframe **asynchronously - doesnt block** , and then it goes immediately to the script section where `aaa` is declared.

What am I missing (im looking for a reason - not a solution). ? what difference does it make if i call onload or onclick ?

*It looks like that the iframe `onload` requires the function at parsing time. ( and not at runtime - when the event actually occurs.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iframe element is not defined as EMPTY. (The content of the element is the content to render if iframes are not supported or are disabled). Consequently, you cannot use XML empty-element syntax to represent the iframe. You need an explicit end tag.

You are providing your script element as the alternative content. If the iframe is rendered the alternative content will be ignored, so the script won't be executed and the function will never be added to the JS environment.

Use `<iframe></iframe>` instead of `<iframe />` and [your non-working example is fixed](http://jsbin.com/ObeQERE/11/).

Comment: phewww...... I thought I was going crazy... thank you very much Quentin ( as always).

Comment: Quentin - a bit off topic : but - does the `async` prop here ----> `var a=createElement('script');    a.async=true;` is exactly the same as here ----> `<script src='...' async >...`. it dont think so because async attr is new to html5 while I've seen many script (which run on old browsers) that used `a.async=true`;

Answer (score 0):

The elements are rendered in the order of them in the code itself. so are scripts(except external scripts when specified with `defer` or `async`). Hence when the `iframe` gets loaded it cannot find immediately the function definition of `aaa` And hence `aaa()` is not called in case of `onload` But in case of `onclick()` both the `script` and the `iframe` has already got loaded before the `click` event occurs(because `click` is executed manually but `load` is automatic).

Hence it's advisable to keep all function definition in the `script` section in the `head` for any future call of those functions.

Comment: But it wont load immediately ! that's what you're missing. and it doesn't block.

Comment: @RoyiNamir What you are questioning is truly intriguing. Need a little more research on it. Now that you commented, it helped me think of it properly about the `blocking`. Thanx anyway for the question. +1 for your question. I think you need all these about `blocking` that you are telling in comment to be mentioned in the question itself to make other realise the viewpoint of the question.